# For loop for detecting the root and printing its xml nodes

Tags: java, xml, itext

I am trying to read the nodes dynamically according to the values sent from the jsp page. But somehow i am stuck in the for loop. 
Suppose i have this xml:

```
<123>
    <a1>A</a1>
    <a2>B</a2>
    <a3>C</a3>
</123>
```

And i am using this function to read nodes and get output:

```
try {
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = 
        new PdfStamper(pdfReader,new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    String xmlRecords = XmlString;
    DocumentBuilder db = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("123");

    for(int i=1; i <= divlen; i++) {             
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(j);
            NodeList aval = element.getElementsByTagName("a"+i);
            Element line = (Element) aval.item(0);
            int avalue = Integer.parseInt(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        }
    }            
    pdfStamper.close();
}
```

where `divlen` is the total number of 'a' which is assigned by jsp page. But how do i run the `for` loop for a1 and a3 node if suppose i delete a2 node and send rest??

Answer (score -1):

In your situation, I would create 3 list (one for each tag a1, a2, a3).

I would have then only the inner for loop (j), in which I put the Element in one of the list according to it's tag name.

Finally, after this loop, I would process each element of each list for whatever purpose I need to do.